# How long do the IP bans last?

Tags: support, ban

I did something bad on SA website and I think that my second IP address is banned from it. Just wondering : how long do those last for?

**(btw , i'm sorry)**

Comment: *as long as it takes*

Comment: I'd email the team and beg for forgiveness and unbannitude.

Comment: Sorry isn't good enough!

Comment: @haikus: You do realize your statement could be the second line of a haiku?

Comment: Banned from the website / Sorry isn't good enough / Repent on Meta!

Comment: Where is this South Australian website you speak of?

Comment: From http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/: "We can automatically detect sockpuppet accounts now. Sockpuppets used for the purpose of upvoting or downvoting will be deleted, and their votes — cancelled."

Comment: @gnostradamus Of course I know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be unusual for a voting puppet account to result in an IP ban (in part, because that is more effort). Normally (especially for a first offence) deleting the puppet account(s) and doing a recalc gets the message across.

Out of curiosity, what are you seeing that makes you think there is an IP ban?

Comment: It fails to resolve page. Maybe by DNS is being weird but I thought I was IP banned. And yeah , my rep got recalculated. I lost half of it.

Comment: Confucius says "You can't lose that which was not yours in the first place". ;)

Comment: A wise man .... :(

Comment: I thought there would be an email warning :(

Comment: I *really* don't think there was an IP block here... The policy on voting is discussed here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/

Comment: Oh, and more here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/

Comment: Confucius says "Man who fart in church sits in his own pue"

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know what "SA" is, but what exactly were you *doing* with that second account? Upvoting the first account? The length of time in the ["penalty box"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) will likely fit the severity of the crime.

Comment: yup , i was doing that :( i think that account is deleted and the ip is banned

Comment: For shame, Nick Brooks. For shame... but at least you've learned something (hopefully).

Comment: i did *sigh* i did

Comment: SA = Something Awful?