# How many days does an IP address ban last?

Tags: support, ip-address, ip-ban

I read [How long do the IP bans last?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33681/215590) but no one provided the **number of days** in their answers.

How many days does an IP address ban last?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depends on the abuse.

Could be days, could be indefinite.

---

I am being completely serious. The "too many requests" tends to be a few minutes, so most people should be fine if they wait for 5-10 minutes before refreshing.

At the same time, we have some IP addresses that have been banned for years and who are still throwing abusive traffic at us (so unlikely to get unbanned any time soon).

Comment: From where the down vote. I think someone didn't like the IP ban. It happened for me 2 times. Just 10 mins